# Selenium starts with user profile but crashes in terminal

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 2")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C://Users//user//AppData//Local//Google//Chrome//User Data")
#options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)


time.sleep(3)
```

```
CONSOLE OUTPUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005B8893+48451]
    (No symbol) [0x0054B8A1]
    (No symbol) [0x00455058]
    (No symbol) [0x00473211]
    (No symbol) [0x00470019]
    (No symbol) [0x004A0798]
    (No symbol) [0x004A047C]
    (No symbol) [0x0049A0B6]
    (No symbol) [0x00477E08]
    (No symbol) [0x00478F2D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00818E3A+2540266]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00858959+2801161]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0085295C+2776588]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00642280+612144]
    (No symbol) [0x00554F6C]
    (No symbol) [0x005511D8]
    (No symbol) [0x005512BB]
    (No symbol) [0x00544857]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77680099+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CA7B6E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CA7B3E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I want to launch selenium and chrome with a specific chrome profile, its loading the profile but crashes in console

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--profile-directory=Profile 2")
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: its still not working

Comment: In this case, this is most likely because you already have chrome running that could use this profile. Try closing all instances of chrome or use the path to the ChromeDriver binary instead of ChromeDriverManager

Comment: I want to add that the workaround with the direct path to the driver does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Which versions of Chrome/chromedriver are you using? Could it be that Chrome has been updated, but you're on a older version of chromedriver?

Another thought is that it could be a display issue. Does it work in headless?

Answer (score -1):

Include the name of the profile in the full path like below:

```
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C://Users//user//AppData//Local//Google//Chrome//User Data//Profile 2")
```

Comment: if i do this its starts but without the profile